# Как ДОБАВЛЯТЬ и удалять определённый текст из input'a при клике на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Надо именно добавлять, а не записывать его заново. И удалять именно определённый текст, а не всё сразу. Спасибо!

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку получить текст, вырезать из него определенную строку и добавить к текущему значению input?

Comment: Да, но как вырезать опр. строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
var btn = document.getElementById('myButton');

btn.onclick = function() {
    input.value += 'click! ';
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="click me!">
```

Попробуйте такой вариант.

Comment: а убирать(ТОЛЬКО ОПРЕДЕЛЁННУЮ ЧАСТЬ ТЕКСТА) как?

Comment: и да, btn.onclick =... - выдаёт ошибку. Исправил на это: $('#myButton').click(function(){...});
Но и главное - inpt.value - тоже ошибка!

Comment: @ArtemPro, попробуй ещё раз. Я изменил ответ. Жми кнопку и смотри что происходит

Comment: @ArtemPro, для удаления части текста читайте [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: можно подробнее ?не  нашел то что мне надо в документации..

Comment: @ArtemPro, распишите подробнее вопрос с примерами. Если документация не помогла, то я без подробной формулировке точно не смогу

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $text = document.querySelector('#text'),
  $buttonAdd = document.querySelector('#button-add'),
    $buttonRemove = document.querySelector('#button-remove'),
    
    defaultText = $text.value; // значение текстового поля на момент загрузки

$buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', function(){
 $text.value = defaultText + 'Additional text';
});

$buttonRemove.addEventListener('click', function(){
 $text.value = defaultText;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="Some text...">
<button id="button-add">Add text</button>
<button id="button-remove">Remove text</button>
```

Comment: в тегах нет jquery, и ваш вариант не будет работать с введенным текстом.

Comment: Во-первых, где в ответе вы видите использование jQuery? Во-вторых, в вопросе ничего не сказано про __введённый__ текст. Написано `именно определённый текст`. Что это за текст? Кем определённый? Не понятно. В третьих, ваш "минус" безсмысленный, мой ответ полностью адекватен вопросу

Comment: Более того, я прокомментировал код, в том месте, где значение __определяется__. Для того что бы вы обратилили внимаение на этот момент и поняли, как этот текст __определяется__ в моём случае. Если речь идёт именно о введённом тексте, то нужно это обозначить в вопросе

Comment: извиняюсь, ваш синтаксис сбил меня с толку. но в случае с инпутом мне кажется очевидным, что текст может меняться.

Comment: Нет, не очевидно. Ваш вопрос очень абстрактный. И даже если бы это было очевидно, не понятно какой текст нужно добавлять и к чему? К тому что ввёл пользователь? А что удалять? А что, если пользователь уже удалил какой-то текст? Может вы приведёте конкретный пример, что и как должно происходить?

Comment: Вы не так поняли вопрос. В input добавляется несколько текстов, а удалять надо только 1 определённый. Как удалить только часть текста?

Comment: `$text.value = $text.value.replace('ОПРЕДЕЛЁННЫЙ ТЕКСТ', '');`